# Android fragments and creating widgets dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is perhaps one of the simpler problems on here, but i am fairly new to android,so still having some challenges.I am downloading some data from a mysql server using JSON.-a list of questions.Each question is then created on its own fragment depending on the total number of questions.I display different widgets-edittext,radiobutton,spinner etc depending on what is specified for that question.

**Problem 1**

My challenge is that,i cannot seem to get the text values entered into/selected from these widgets.This  works well in different activities of the application,but it is just this fragment class where i get issues.

**Problem 2**

I am also trying to get the positions of each question,from so that i can properly display the next/back buttons appropriately.e.g if i am at the 1st que,hide back button,if at the end,hide next and display done.something like that.My current implementation only works if i don't press button back to view a previous question.if i do,then button done is't displayed when i get to the last item,but it still shows 'next'

**Problem 3**

I also tried inserting checks for the input fields.e.g if user clicks next without entering anything,display toast and do not move to next item.But mine still goes to next page,and displays the toast msg "response is required"
Kindly help me see what i am doing wrong in my implementation.Thanks

My relevant code below

```
**fragmentStatePagerAdapter class**

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    public PagerAdapter adapter;

    Question question;

    Context context2;

    public PagerAdapter(Context c, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context2 = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("inside get count");

        return questions.size(); // get number of pages to be displayed
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Log.i("at PagerAdapter", "yaaay!!At pager adapter");

        Fragment fragment = null;

        Question que = questions.get(i); //questions is the arraylist that has been     populated with question objects from the server.

        // pass value to be displayed in inflated view

        fragment = new FragmentRadioButton(context2, que);

        return fragment;

    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        position++;
        String s = "Question  " + position;// setting the title

        return s;
    }

}
```

**The Fragment class**

```
public class FragmentRadioButton extends Fragment {
Context context3;
private Question question;
private RadioButton[] radioButton;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout1;
static ViewPager mViewPager = FragmentStatePagerActivity.mViewPager;
private TextView question_txtView;
private RadioGroup radiogroup;
private Button btnNext;
private Spinner spinner;
private RatingBar ratingBar;
private Button btnBack;
private EditText editText;
private Button btnDone;
private TextView countRating_txt;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout2;
private static final int radio_button = 1;

private static final int m_spinner = 2;

private static final int edit_text = 3;

private static final int rating_bar = 4;
public static ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private List<RadioGroup> allRadioGroups = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();

private List<Spinner> allSpinners = new ArrayList<Spinner>();

private List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

List<RatingBar> allRatingBars = new ArrayList<RatingBar>();

public FragmentRadioButton() {

}

public FragmentRadioButton(Context c, Question que) {
    this.context3 = c;

    this.question = que;
}
//@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_radio_button, null);

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.scrollViewRadioButton);

    relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) scrollView
            .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) relativeLayout1
            .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
    context3 = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
try {
question_txtView = (TextView) relativeLayout1
                .findViewById(R.id.question_text_radio_button);
        question_txtView.setText(question.getDescription());
num.add(question.getQuestionId());
if (question.getWidgetId() == radio_button) {

            radiogroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            radioButton = new RadioButton[question.getAnswers().size()];

            Typeface font4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                    .getAssets(), "fonts/enriqueta/Enriqueta-Regular.otf");

            for (int i = 0; i < question.getAnswers().size(); i++) {

                radioButton[i] = new RadioButton(context3);
                radioButton[i].setLines(3);
                radioButton[i].setText(question.getAnswers().get(i)
                        .getAnswer_Text());
                radioButton[i].setTag(question.getAnswers().get(i)
                        .getAnswer_Id());
                radioButton[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                radioButton[i].setTypeface(font4);
                radioButton[i].setTextSize(30);

                radiogroup.addView(radioButton[i]);
                radiogroup.isClickable();
}

            allRadioGroups.add(radiogroup);

        } else if (question.getWidgetId() == m_spinner) {

            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int b = 0; b < question.getAnswers().size(); b++) {

                String data = question.getAnswers().get(b).getAnswer_Text()
                        .toString();

                spinner.setTag(question.getAnswers().get(b).getAnswer_Id());

                list.add(data);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    context3, R.layout.my_style, list) {

                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTextSize(22);

                    return v;
                }

                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                            parent);

                    ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    return v;
                }
            };

            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            allSpinners.add(spinner);

        } else if (question.getWidgetId() == edit_text) {
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            allEds.add(editText);

        } else if (question.getWidgetId() == rating_bar) {

            ratingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            countRating_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ratingBar
                    .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar rating_bar,
                                float rating, boolean fromUser) {

                            rating = rating_bar.getRating();

                            countRating_txt.setText(String.valueOf(rating)
                                    + "Ratings");

                        }
                    });

            allRatingBars.add(ratingBar);

        }

        // }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Log error :",
                "could not write the text views in radioButton fragment");

    }
ItemPosition();

    return view;
}
OnClickListener btnNextOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (question.getWidgetId() == radio_button) {

            validatedRadioGroup();

        } else if (question.getWidgetId() == m_spinner) {


            validatedSpinner();

        } else if (question.getWidgetId() == edit_text) {

            validatedEditText();

        } else if (question.getWidgetId() == rating_bar) {

            validatedRatingBar();
        }


        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);

    }

};

OnClickListener btnBackOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);

    }

};

OnClickListener btnDoneOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int lastItem = question.getQuestionIds().size();
        if (lastItem == question.getQuestionIds().size()) {

            if (question.getWidgetId() == radio_button) {

                radioText();

            } else if (question.getWidgetId() == m_spinner) {

                spinnerText();

            } else if (question.getWidgetId() == edit_text) {

                EditText_Value();

            } else if (question.getWidgetId() == rating_bar) {

                ratingText();
            }

            Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(), FinishedSurvey.class);

            startActivity(a);

        }
    }

};


}

public void ItemPosition() {

    for (int j = 0; j < num.size(); j++) {

        // int item = num.indexOf(j);

        if (j == 0) {

            btnBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            btnDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            System.out.println("the first part");

        } else if (!(j == 0 || (j == question.getQuestionIds().size() - 1))) {

            btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            btnDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            System.out.println("the second part");

        } else {

            if (j == question.getQuestionIds().size() - 1) {

                btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                btnDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                System.out.println("the last part");

            }

        }

    }


}
```